# redirect all client http url with android hotspot

Tags: android, redirect

I try to make app to share my file with open my mobile hotspot, and friend can connect it .
Then open browser key in url to download.
I use iptables to redirect from port 80 to my web server port 8888, it works.
But when I change /etc/hosts file/ add 1'92.168.43.1 xx.com'

it's fail for client to used.
I ping the xx.com at my hotspot phone and it works.

I try at android 2.3.7 xiaomi  android root enviroment
Use nandhttpserver library 
(I try use dns server app, but failed(I have redirect port 53 to dns server))
Can any one help me?

my host script

```
private boolean chnagehost(String appendStr) {
    boolean res; 
    String temp ="mount -o rw,remount -t rootfs /;mount -o remount,rw -t yaffs2 /dev/block/mtdblock3 /system;"
            +"cp -f /etc/hosts /etc/hosts.backup;"
            +"echo "+ appendStr + " >> /etc/hosts;echo -e '\n\r' >> /etc/hosts";

    res = executeRootShellCommand(temp);
    //res = executeShellCommand("cp -f /etc/hosts /etc/hosts.backup");

    //res= executeShellCommand("echo "+ appendStr + " >> /etc/hosts");
     return res;
}
```

Comment: i just a junior developer and develop in mobile ^ ^

Comment: what ??.............

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find it.
It's should restart hotspot after modify hosts file.
The hosts works.
Tested for samsung phone , android 4.3 , 4.1